# How to send variable with the guzzle get method

Tags: php, guzzle

I need to modify the php code of a query to APi AbuseIPDB.
I would like to populate the "ipAddress" field with a variable that contains the IP address.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
      'base_uri' => 'https://api.abuseipdb.com/api/v2/'
    ]);

    $response = $client->request('GET', 'check', [
        'query' => [
            'ipAddress' => $ipline,
            'maxAgeInDays' => '90',
        ],
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Key' => 'API_KEY'
      ],
    ])
```

I added the character ' to the variable $ipline.

```
$ipline="'".$ipline."'"
```

An error appears with the current code:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `GET https://api.abuseipdb.com/api/v2/check?ipAddress=%2769.47.25.186%27&maxAgeInDays=90` resulted in a `422 Unprocessable Entity` response: {"errors":[{"detail":"The ip address must be a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address (e.g. 8.8.8.8 or 2001:4860:4860::8888).","stat (truncated...) in C:\xampp\htdocs\blacklist\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:113 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\blacklist\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(69): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), NULL, Array, NULL) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\blacklist\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(204): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\blacklist\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(153): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), NULL) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\blacklist\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\TaskQueue.php(48): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\blacklist\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(248): GuzzleHttp\Promise\TaskQueue->run(true) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\blacklist\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(224): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitFn() #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\blacklist\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(269): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending() #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\blacklist\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(226): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitList() #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\blacklist\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(62): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending() #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\blacklist\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(187): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->wait() #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\blacklist\index.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Client->request('GET', 'check', Array) #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\blacklist\index.php(13): abusei_checkip(''69.47.25.186'') #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\blacklist\index.php(57): getip() #13 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\blacklist\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php on line 113
```

Comment: _"I added the character ' to the variable $ipline."_ - why? Did it say anywhere that you should pass it that way?

Comment: Drop the single quotes, they're not necessary in a URL query parameter

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 situation:

1. you have 1 IP6 and 1 IP4 on server, but by default server will use IP6 for CURL library.

In this situation you just need to set **'force_ip_resolve' => 'v4'** in send command:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->post(
    'https://xxx/api/auth/login',
    [
        'force_ip_resolve' => 'v4',...
```

2. Another situation, is that you have multiple IP4 on server.
   In this situation you must set **config** in send command:

   $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
   $response = $client->post(
   'https://s2api1.sitesapi.com/api/auth/login',
   [
   'config' => [
   'curl' => [
   CURLOPT_INTERFACE => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
   ]
   ],...